# How do I make 1 change a second

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some trouble getting my code to work. I want to have a picture move only 1 time every 1 second. What happens now is that it keeps going places where I click and continueing the animation afterwards, and I don't want that. This is my sercaint script:

```
$(bullet_place).ready(function() {
    $(".range").click(function(e) {

        $("#bullet_place").delay(50).fadeIn(0);
        var x = e.pageX - 27, 
            y = e.pageY - 22;
        $("#place").html("<style type=text/css> #bullet_place { position: fixed; > left: " + x + "; top:" + y + "; width: 50px; } </style>");
        $("#bullet_place").delay(750).fadeOut(500);
    })
});
```

Comment: `.html("<style type=text/css> #bullet_place`.. I think you should consider using `.css()` here.

Comment: I already tryed that, but it didn't work, but thanks

Comment: Place function inside setInteval(){}

Comment: What do you mean "1 time every 1 second"? Instead of a click handler, or throttle the click handler to limit it to once a second, or once a second forever after it's clicked? You have to explain this **a lot** better.

Comment: What I mean is that i want to have my code NOT being albe to activate for 1 second from the points it being activated.

Comment: So throttle the click handler then ?

Comment: You know it takes 1.25 seconds for the bullet_place to appear completely in it's new location ?

Comment: The biggest problem here is that we are not on one line + I'm very new to jQuery. This is for a school project of mine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with a suitable JQuery method, but if it helps at all, try making use of the following: `d = new Date();` then `d.getTime()`. This gives you a millisecond representation of the current time. (But you will need to call 'new Date' for each interval you want to check). Would you have ideas on how to use that to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **only the document has a ready handler**.
Secondly, only the head section should contain style tags (this is about to change in newer browsers).

To throttle the click, use `on()` and `off()` with a timeout

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".range").on('click', move);
});

function move(e) {

    $(".range").off('click');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".range").on('click', move);
    }, 1000);

    $("#bullet_place").delay(50)
                      .fadeIn(0)
                      .css({
                          position : 'fixed',
                          left     : e.pageX - 27,
                          top      : e.pageY - 22,
                          width    : '50px'
                      });

    $("#bullet_place").delay(750).fadeOut(500); // you're sure you shouldn't
}                                               // be using a callback ?
```

Comment: i know, and i´ll remember. btw, if i use this in the same file again, and change the words, will it work than again?

Answer (score 0):

If i get it right, after click you need to unbind or restrict the click event, and after your animation is done (in the callback function) readd the event.
This may look like this (UNTESTED!):

```
    var clickEvent = true;
    $(".range").click(function (e) {
        if (clickEvent) {
            clickEvent = false;
            $("#bullet_place").delay(50).fadeIn(0);
            var x = e.pageX - 27,
                y = e.pageY - 22;
            $("#place").html("<style type=text/css> #bullet_place { position: fixed; > left: " + x + "; top:" + y + "; width: 50px; } </style>");
            $("#bullet_place").delay(750).fadeOut(500, function () {
                clickEvent = true;
            });
        }
    });
```